# Mahout Recommender no output - about input file format

Tags: mahout, mahout-recommender

I'am using mahout-distribution-0.9. I have a problem in my program.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model.DataModel;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.similarity.UserSimilarity;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.similarity.PearsonCorrelationSimilarity;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.neighborhood.UserNeighborhood;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.neighborhood.NearestNUserNeighborhood;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.recommender.RecommendedItem;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.recommender.Recommender;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.GenericUserBasedRecommender;


class RecommenderIntro {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            DataModel model =
            //new FileDataModel (new File("F:\\ml-10M100K\\intro.csv"));
            new FileDataModel (new File("F:\\ml-10M100K\\ratingsShort.dat"),"::");

            UserSimilarity similarity = new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity (model);
            UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new NearestNUserNeighborhood (2, similarity, model);
            Recommender recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender (model, neighborhood, similarity);
            List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = recommender.recommend(1, 2);
            for (RecommendedItem recommendation : recommendations) {
                    System.out.println(recommendation);
            }

    }
}
```

The content in File intro.csv is like:

```
1,101,5.0
1,102,3.0
1,103,2.5
2,101,2.0
2,102,2.5
2,103,5.0
```

When I use intro.csv to run this ,it has output in eclipse:

```
RecommendedItem[item:104, value:4.257081]
RecommendedItem[item:106, value:4.0]
```

The content in File ratingsShort.dat is like:

```
1::122::5::838985046
1::185::5::838983525
1::231::5::838983392
1::292::5::838983421
2::733::3::868244562
2::736::3::868244698
```

or change the content of ratingsShort.dat to :

```
1,539,5
1,589,5
2,110,5
2,151,3
2,733,3
2,802,2
2,1210,4
2,1544,3
3,1246,4
3,1408,3.5
3,1552,2
3,1564,4.5
```

When I use ratingsShort.dat,there is no output in eclipse.

```
FileDataModel(File dataFile, String delimiterRegex)
```

The method in Mahout support this usage,but why it has no output?

Can anybody who give me some advise? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.I figure out my problem.I changed my movielens from ml-10m.zip to ml-1m.zip. It does have output.

So,This issue is because THE DATASET I intercept IS not appropriate!The intro.csv from Internet is

sufficient for mahout to caculate the recommend value but not my dataset that I cut as will.

Answer (score 0):

You need to translate your IDs into Mahout IDs. Mahout treats user and items IDs as the row and column numbers of the rating. So the first ID for row/user will be "0", which corresponds to your id of "1", The same for column/item IDs. If your IDs were only the ones shown above they would need to be translated to Mahout ids as below:

```
0,2,5
0,3,5
1,0,5
1,1,3
1,4,3
1,5,2
1,6,4
1,10,3
2,7,4
2,8,3.5
2,9,2
2,11,4.5
```

It doesn't matter how you map row/user and column/item IDs to mahout IDs (i did it above by sort order but this is not required) but the Mahout IDs must be contiguous non-negative integers. Then when you get recommendations they must be translated back into your IDs.